# Why is OpenJDK not preinstalled?

Tags: java, openjdk

I don't understand why OpenJDK is not preinstalled. A bunch of applications depend on it and it only takes up 0,7MB.

Of course there is the unneeded "OpenJDK Policy Tool" icon but Canonical could easily remove that.

Why has Canonical chosen to not preinstall OpenJDK?

Comment: Because it is no necessory

Comment: Why is <insert program name> not preinstalled? Oh, you can ask this question for about anything, really.

Comment: On meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6915/134848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `openjdk-7-jre` package *is* 0.7MB but it has dependencies that would also need to be included. The major one being `openjdk-7-jre-headless` which is 49.5MB. There are more.

When you're trying to cram as much as you can into a space as small as you can make it, the JRE that nothing on the CD depends on is an expensive gesture.